# Understanding closure of a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am taking a first course in Abstract Algebra during the summer and have a question about how groups work.

Let's say I have a group $G$ and an element $h$ that is not in $G$. If I take any element $g$ from G, is $gh$ ever in G ? What about for all elements in $G$ with $h$ under the operation?

My intuition tells me that a group should contain all elements that are closed with all other elements under the operation.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you're a little confused - or perhaps not quite fully understanding things yet! If you have a group $G$, what do you mean by "an element $h$ that is not in $G$? How could you know what the product $hg$ is in that case? When you speak of "elements" above, what do you mean?

Comment: For example of I took the even integers under addition, but then tried to add some odd number. I can see that an odd plus an even is an odd, so this would not work. If it did happen to work, then it should guarantee the element was actually in the group?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? Since $h$ is not in $G$ what do you define as $gh$?Is your question how to define $gh$ such that we get a minimal group $G'\supseteq{}G\cup\{h\}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is $h$? If $h$ isn't an element of $G$ then it's unclear what the product $gh$ means.

One situation in which it does make sense is when $G$ is a subgroup of a group $H$, and $h \in H \setminus G$. Then $gh$ makes sense because $H$ is a group, and the product is with respect to the group operation of $H$.

In this case, if $G \leq H$, and $g \in G, h \in H \setminus G$ then $gh$ is never in $G$. If it was, $g^{-1}gh = h$ would be in $G$.

Comment: You accidentally put $H \setminus H$ instead of $H \setminus G$.

Answer (score 0):

As some have noticed your notation is quite confusing as you can't define the product of two elements if they are not in the same groupe, i.e. you can't write $h.g$ if one of the two elements aren't in the group.

But to answer your question if I can understand it, it is not always the case. Take $(\mathbb Z, +)$  which is a group. Then take $n\in \mathbb Z$ and $x\in \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Z$ (e.g $x = \pi$). Then

$$ n + x \notin \mathbb Z$$